# Change background colour of button when clicked

Tags: angularjs

I would like to change the background colour of a button when it is clicked

HTML code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="style1()">
        Celsius
    </button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="style2()">
        Fahrenheit
    </button>
</div>
```

Angular code where the background colours of the buttons should be changed:

```
$scope.style
 {
 };
$scope.style2
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do it this way

```js
angular.module('myapp',[]).controller('testCtrl', function($scope){});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div class="btn-group" ng-init="style={'background-color' : 'green'}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-style="style1"
            ng-click="style1=style; style2=null">Celsius</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-style="style2"
            ng-click="style2=style; style1=null">Fahrenheit</button>
  </div>
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: for two buttons it shows two different colors but i want only one color that switches between two buttons

Comment: @VJayanthReddy I've updated the answer. Please look.

Comment: @VJayanthReddy How this can be achieved in angular 6. I have multiple buttons i want to highlight on click

Comment: @indu did you ever figure out how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can prepare css class:

```
.clicked 
{
color:red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="buttonClick('Celsius')" ng-class="{'clicked': selectedButton== 'Celsius'  }">
            Celsius
        </button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="buttonClick('Fahrenheit')" ng-class="{'clicked': selectedButton== 'Fahrenheit'  }">
            Fahrenheit
        </button>
    </div>
```

and give a class name in click function:

```
$scope.buttonClick= function (s){$scope.selectedButton =s }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ms403Ly8/38/

Comment: i cannot able to understand what you are saying

Comment: but there is no change in background color

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ng-class` or `ng-style` which apply a css style or class based on a scope expression. See the angular documentation for details.

Comment: @joe_young Just my opinion but I'd tend to disagree. Its a valid answer, and using angular means regularly using their documentation. ng-class or ng-style can be very powerful and seems a perfect fit.

Answer (score 0):

Take help from this code

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<title>example</title>
<style type="text/css">

  .red{
    color:red;
  }
  .blue{
    color:blue;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="con">
<div ng-class="class">{{class}}</div>
<button ng-click="changeClass()">Change Class</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module("app",[]);

  app.controller("con",function($scope){

    $scope.class = "red";

    $scope.changeClass = function(){
      if ($scope.class === "red")
        $scope.class = "blue";
      else
        $scope.class = "red";
    };
  });
</script>
```