# How to change color of a button inside an Angular js function using the same button?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using a function for the ng-click in a button to filter a list. I need to change the color of the button when it is clicked once and displaying the filtered list. I need to do this inside the same function which is called by the ng-click. How can I do that without using separate css file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414912/change-background-colour-of-button-when-clicked

Comment: It is using two buttons. But I want to change color of the same button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user3724599 from your question my understanding you want to change the color of button on ng-click.

Here I attached JsFiddle link. Here I show 2 buttons.

1. Once you click the button color will be changed again it won't reset to default color
2. On each click it will change to default and alternate color.

https://jsfiddle.net/otLgasLe/

Please check this. Please let me know it's answer your question.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-view="">
 <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="color ? 'btn-success' : ''"  ng-click="btnClick()" >Success</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="color2 ? 'btn-warning' : 'btn-success'" ng-click="btnclick2()">Alternate</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to do it using the same button not using two different butoons

Comment: here I explained with single button ng-click only. But I showed 2 example for your understanding