# Changing the background colour of a button (On/Off)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have reviewed [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414912/change-background-colour-of-button-when-clicked) but I am not using angular.

Here is my code so far:

```
<button id='Bx' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "#Bx")'>Bx</button>
<button id='By' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "#Bx")'>By</button>
<button id='Bz' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "#Bx")'>Bz</button>
```

With my JS like this:

```
function toggleClickedBuz( bizStr , id ) {
    if(clickedBusinesses.includes(bizStr)){
       // removing duplicate element from that array, dependant on button pressed
       clickedBusinesses = clickedBusinesses.filter( cb => cb !== bizStr );
       document.getElementById( id ).style.backgroundColor='white';
    }else{
        // else push it to the array
       clickedBusinesses.push(bizStr)
       document.getElementById( id ).style.backgroundColor='red';
    }
    console.log(clickedBusinesses)
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Despite having this in my CSS:

```
.canvas .button-box button {
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 10vw;
    margin-top: 0.5vh;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: When you use getElementById you don't need to add # so change `toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "#Bx")` to `toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "Bx")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given following HTML

```
<button id='Bx' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "#Bx")'>Bx</button>
```

You are passing `#Bx` as id argument to your toggle function. This results in the js call:

```
document.getElementById("#Bx");
```

But the `getElementById` function does not require the `#` prefix. Try to change your HTML to

```
<button id='Bx' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "Bx")'>Bx</button>
```

to hotfix your current problem

Comment: Thank you, this works. It's a shame I lost my rep though!

Answer (score 2):

Simple, You don't need `#` in `toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "#Bx")`. Put `id` without `#`. The function `getElementById()` already refers the id. So you don't need to specify using `#`.

**Your HTML should be like**

```
<button id='Bx' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "Bx")'>Bx</button>
<button id='By' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "Bx")'>By</button>
<button id='Bz' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "Bx")'>Bz</button>
```

Comment: Do you mean without the #tags in your code or with?

Comment: without the # tag

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `#` in your button. This much is enough:

```
<button id='Bx' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx","Bx")'>Bx</button>
<button id='By' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx","Bx")'>By</button>
<button id='Bz' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx","Bx")'>Bz</button>
```

`#` is a CSS selector whuch selects your HTML `id` elements. You can reference them in your CSS in this manner:

```
#Bx {
  color: #AAAAAA;
}
```